# Derivative of square root of absolute value of dereminant

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Consider the matrix $G=G(\alpha)$ and the **absolute value of its determinant** $|g|=abs(det(G))$

is there a closed form formula for the derivative of its square root $\frac{\partial\sqrt{|g|}}{\partial\alpha}$ ?

Comment: By the chain rule, we can write this as
$$
\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{|g|}} \cdot \frac{\partial |g|}{\partial a},
$$
but it's not clear that this has a closed form expression

Comment: Actually, using the numerator layout identities [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities), we have
$$
\frac{\partial |g|^2}{\partial a} = 2|g|^2g^{-1},
$$
so that the derivative of the fourth root of this is (by the chain rule)
$$
\frac 1{4 |g|^{3/2}} \cdot 2|g|^2g^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{|g|}g^{-1}.
$$